# .NET 7.0 - Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'. User obtained by usermanager and added to List

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-7.0

On .NET 7.0, code first, Repository pattern, Specification pattern.

After creating obj A and B in DB, I'm assigning a many-to-many relationship between them, generating a duplicated PK error in one table.

This is my code:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IAuditable
{
    // ...
    public virtual IList<Report> Reports { get; set; }
}

public class Report : EntityBase, IAuditable
{
    // ...
    public virtual IList<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
 public class ConstructionReportContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
 {
     // ...
     public DbSet<ApplicationUser>? ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Report>? ConstructionReports { get; set; }
}
```

In DB, the migration creates table `ApplicationUserReport` with both FK to `User` and `Report`.

Method: Edit, this method is in ServiceRpoert. So the entity object is for Report.

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
public async Task AddUserToReport(ManageUserToReportDto dto)
    {
        try
        {
            var entity = _repository.Find(new GetReportWithUsers(true, dto.Id)).FirstOrDefault();
            if(entity == null)
                throw new BusinessLogicException(string.Format(ExceptionMessages.EntityNotFund, "Reporte"));

            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(dto.UserId.ToString());

            if(user == null)
                throw new BusinessLogicException(string.Format(ExceptionMessages.EntityNotFund, "Usuario"));

            if (entity.Users.Any(x => x.Id == dto.UserId.ToString()))
                throw new BusinessLogicException($"El usuario '{user.UserName}' ya se encuentra ingresado en el reporte.");

            entity.Users.Add(user);
            await _repository.EditAsync(entity);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
2023-11-07 15:34:58.480 -03:00 [ERR] InnerException: | Trace-id: '95237348-5f39-4ed8-9b86-5fb5731b880b'
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetUsers'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'. The duplicate key value is (ddc9205d-aa3c-479d-9217-01c3404a4c61).
The statement has been terminated.
```

I also tried to attach the user object before doing the add and I got the same result.
Is method FindByIdAsync from UserManagaer, detaching the object?

Comment: The code is trying to add a user that already exists in "dbo.AspNetUsers".

Comment: @pcalkins well, that is what the error looks like. But the code add the user in a list and edit. Should only save the association

Comment: I never did get how EF handles many-to-many, I always handle them myself, and avoid using lists, but it looks likes like something is trying to add a new user to AspNetUsers table.  Maybe avoid using "entity" as a variable name?

Comment: The only thing you should need to set is the foreign key for "user" in the linking table.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the Context was being createad as transient and that why the method FindByIdAsync was detaching the user.

I change to

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
    {
        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 15, maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), errorNumbersToAdd: null);
    });
},
 ServiceLifetime.Scoped  //Showing explicitly that the DbContext is shared across the HTTP request scope (graph of objects started in the HTTP request)
);
```